HTTP request sent, awaiting response.. ERROR 403: Forbidden
сразу скажу я далек от этой всей темы. Все время настраивал себе прокси манулпо этому мануалу и все было хорошо. С подключением первого прокси проблем нету, проблема возникает когда вписывают команду " wget http://fjedi.com/init_server.sh ". Настраиваю прокси через "Putty". Может быть есть люди, которые знают как решить проблему.

